# Python: Expected expression error on end if

Tags: python, pylance

I'm quite new to the Python programming language and am just working on a basic project to sort of try to grasp the basics. This may have been asked before but I can't really get a clear answer (most of the answers I see don't include end if). I'm not sure if it means that I've used wrong spacing somewhere or if I'm missing a semi colon (does Python have those?) somewhere.

My code

```
print("----Places to visit app---")
print("1. Insert a place")
print("2. Print places")
print("3. Delete a place")
print("4. Exit")
print("5. Please enter your choice")
option = input()
if option == '1':
    print("Please enter the name of the place: ")
    place_name = input()
    print("please enter the address of the place: ")
    place_address = input()
    print("please enter the number of days you plan to stay at this place: ")
    num_days = int(input())
    print("Please enter the amount you plan to spend per day")
    daily_cost=float(input())
    total_cost=num_days*daily_cost
    print("-----Place Added-----")
    print("Place name: ", place_name)
    print("Address: ", place_address)
    print("Number of Days: ", num_days)
    print("Total cost: $", total_cost)
elif option == '2':
   print("Print places feature will be develped in future...")
elif option == '3':
   print("Delete a place feature will be develped in future...")
elif option == '4':
   print("Goodbye!!!")
else:
   print("Invalid option selected. Please choose a valid option.")
end if
```

Error on line 31 (end if): Expected expression Pylance

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `end if` is valid Python syntax?

Comment: I'm following a tutorial, which has that in it. Also, I've tried it without the end if and my program just did not execute. It just got stuck in the compilation process.

Comment: Are you sure your tutorial didn't have `# end if` ( a comment)?

Comment: `end` statements are not used in python. Nesting logic is handled by indentation.

Comment: Are you sure that's Python tutorial?

Comment: Python programs are not compiled (well, they kinda are, but not under usual understanding)

Comment: @matszwecja ah ok yeah I'm pretty new to python, some things feel a little different compared to .net languages. Yeah I'm sure its a Pyton tutorial, its content from a university course that I have with me.

Comment: @Sayse the tutorial maybe forgot to add that hash I'm not sure lol. I guess it could be a comment.

Comment: In that case look at the syntax they are using in the tutorial and make sure you are not missing any #, the indenting is exactly as they have it etc.

Comment: @Daraan hmm ok that does make sense.

Comment: added the # and that fixed it, weird that removing end if earlier gave me issues...anyhoo that's working now, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mistaking some keywords.

1. `end if` is not valid syntax, keyword in python
2. Python is scoped by indentation. So your `if` block actually ended at the last `print('Invalid...')` line

It's like this

```
if true:
    # inside if
else: # since you did not indent/tab here ends the if scope
    # inside else
    # this is also inside since indented
# This is no longer inside, the block ended when there's nothing at the same indent level
```

Comment: This was helpful in checking my code as well, thanks. Commenting out that end if line with a # seemed to fix it.

Comment: Why did you use `//` instead of `#`?

Comment: I forgot the python syntax, thank you @Remmelzwaal. Updated in the answer